# Row touched gotoScene with id name "Corona SDK"

Tags: android, ios, lua, tableview, coronasdk

I am trying to go to a new scene on row touch. I want the row that is touched to go to the scene with the same file name as the id name. I hope that this is not too confusing. The problem is in the Function rowtouch. Here is my code. Thank You in advance.

```
            local hike = {}
hike[1] = { name="Bell Canyon",    difficulty="Easy" }
hike[2] = { name="Donut Falls",  difficulty="Easy" }
hike[3] = { name="Hidden Peak",   difficulty="Medium" }
hike[4] = { name="Dog Lake",   difficulty="Easy" }
hike[5] = { name="Mary, Martha", difficulty="Easy" }
hike[6] = { name="Catherine",  difficulty="Easy" }

function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

        local function onRowRender( event )

local row = event.row
   local id = row.index


   row.nameText = display.newText( hike[id].name, 12, 0, native.systemFont, 45 )
   row.nameText.anchorX = 0
   row.nameText.anchorY = 0.5
   row.nameText:setFillColor( 0 )
   row.nameText.y = 50
   row.nameText.x = 25

   row.difficultyText = display.newText( hike[id].difficulty, 12, 0, native.systemFont, 24 )
   row.difficultyText.anchorX = 0
   row.difficultyText.anchorY = 0.5
   row.difficultyText:setFillColor( 0.5 )
   row.difficultyText.y = 110
   row.difficultyText.x = 25


   row.arrow = display.newText( ">", 12, 0, native.systemFont, 35 )
   row.arrow.anchorX = 0
   row.arrow.anchorY = 0.5
   row.arrow:setFillColor( .5 )
   row.arrow.y = 110
   row.arrow.x = display.contentWidth - 50




   row:insert( row.nameText )
   row:insert( row.difficultyText )
   row:insert( row.arrow )
   return true
end



function RowTouch( event )
if event.phase == "release" then
    composer.gotoScene( event.target.hike[id].name )
    end 
end



 myTable = widget.newTableView
    {
        width = display.contentWidth, 
        height = display.contentHeight,
        backgroundColor = { .47, .66, .53 },
        topPadding = 0,
        hideBackground = false,
        onRowRender = onRowRender,
        onRowTouch = RowTouch,
        noLines = true,
    }



    for i=1, #hike do
        myTable:insertRow{
        rowHeight = 220,
        isCategory = false,
        lineColor = { .47, .66, .53 }
        }
    end
end
```

Comment: Please describe the undesired effect you are currently getting or include an error.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should add an extra field to your "hike" table:

```
hike[1] = { name="Bell Canyon",    difficulty="Easy",  sceneName="bellcanyon" }
```

Then

```
composer.gotoScene( hike[event.target.index].sceneName )
```

That way you can have a display name that will for human reading and a string dedicated for the composer scene to go to.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing

```
composer.gotoScene( hike[event.target.index].name );
```

names of hikes have spaces and commas in them and are not the best file names.